# Unable to retrieve the email using Firebase Admin SDK auth()

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

Sorry, if I am missing something simple.

In my cloud function, I am trying to extract the email info. of an user [using the uid](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#retrieve_user_data). 
Sample json output for the id xyz which is created using Facebook sign in. The email does exists for the user (Verified in the console).

```
  uid: 'xyz',
  email: undefined,
  emailVerified: false,
```

Checked the [admin.auth.UserRecord](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord) interface and there is something mentioned as

> The user's primary email, if set.

Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: I can't reproduce your results using `firebase-admin` 5.9.1.  Are you using a different version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be 2 reasons for this:

- The facebook user does not have an email or chose not to share it.
- You are using "multiple accounts per email" which only sets the email in the providerData for OAuth users. Try checking the `userRecord.providerData[0].email`

Comment: I think "multiple accounts per email" should be the reason. (Though I changed it in between). Accepted the answer.